# How is the Representer theorem used in the derivation of the SVM dual form?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lagrange-multipliers, duality

This is the primal form of the SVM hypothesis :
$$
h _{\mathbf{\vec w}, b}(\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}) = \mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b
$$
The Representer theorem as formulated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representer_theorem#:%7E:text=of%20a%20regularized%20empirical%20risk,in%20the%20training%20set%20data.) expresses the *optimal* weight vector as a linear combination of the training examples :
$$
\mathbf{\vec w}^{*} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\mu_{i}^{*}y ^{(i)}\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}
$$
This can be derived using the Lagrange multiplier method.
Now, the dual form of the SVM hypothesis is given as :
$$
h _{\boldsymbol{\vec \mu}, b} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\mu_{j}^{*}y ^{(i)} \langle\mathbf{\vec x}^{(j)}, \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}\rangle +\, b ^{*}
$$
Here, we have clearly substituted the weight vector $\mathbf{\vec w}$ using the Representer theorem.

> However, the weight vector in the original SVM hypothesis is *not* the optimal weight vector. So, why can we substitute the weight vector in the primal form using the Representer theorem?

Answer (score 0):

The representer theorem isn't needed for SVM. The solution form comes out on its own just by solving for the dual (i.e., introducing variables for the constraint, and through the KKT conditions).

Comment: But isn't the dual form of SVM derived *using* the Representer theorem? Moreover, we typically apply the stationarity KKT condition on the gradient of the Lagrangian by setting it to 0 : $\nabla _{\vec w ^ *} L(\vec w ^ *, b ^ *, \vec \mu ^ *) = \vec 0$ . Without using the Representer theorem, how exactly will we substitute $\vec w ^ *$ ?

Comment: See https://medium.com/@sathvikchiramana/svm-dual-formulation-7535caa84f17